# No module named 'kafka' - Python project run through bazel

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, bazel

I'm a Java developer and a python beginner. I'm trying to import kafka into a python service I'm writing. This is being run through bazel. I installed kafka-python using

```
pip install kafka-python
```

I was able to do kafka calls through a jupyter notebook so can confirm that the kafka-python library is installed. I imported the kafka-python library in my code using

```
from kafka.admin import KafkaAdminClient
```

However, when I try to run the service

```
bazel run //service:service_image.binary
```

I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kafka'`. I tried looking for how to inject dependency for kafka, like we do for java using maven/pom/gradle using a version of `'org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:<version>'` but couldn't find anything. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling kafka-python. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stuck with a problem like this, I figured out the solution by using [rules_python](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python). Created a requirements.txt which I pointed to using `compile_pip_requirements` rule defined in `rules_python` [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/main/examples/pip_parse/BUILD.bazel#L58). Added something like this to the BUILD file

```
load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "compile_pip_requirements")

compile_pip_requirements(
    name = "requirements",
    requirements_in = "//third_party:python_requirements.txt",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have `kafka` package installed on the same environment as where you have `kafka-python` installed. If yes, delete if and reinstall `kafka-python` with:

```
pip uninstall kafka     
pip uninstall kafka-python
pip install kafka-python
```